# How to read a session with a PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session

I Know A PHPSESSID in the server how can i read a session variable that is set to a PHPSESSID ( i don't want to use $_SESSION because i don't want start session in this thread ) i only want read session data with using PHPSESSID ?? 
PHP :

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
class readSession extends \Thread {
    private $sess_id,$data_name;
    public function __construct($SESSID,$data_name){
        $this->sess_id = $SESSID;
        $this->data_name = $data_name;
    }
    public function run(){
        $data = $this->readSession($this->sess_id,$this->data_name);   
    }
    private function readSession($SESSID,$data_name){
        session_id($SESSID);
        session_start();
        $temp = $_SESSION[$data_name];
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
        return $temp;
    }    
}
```

i write this code to read users session's data but it remove the users session data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, reading another user's session data is a *horrible* idea. If you need to have shared access to that data - don't store it in the session.

Secondly, reading another doing it via `session_start()` with the same session ID is an even worse idea - that way you are effectively *acting* as that user. There's no easy/reliable way to read session data without intercepting it, but that's not by accident, it's exactly because you shouldn't do it.

That being said, don't call `session_destroy()` and the user's data won't be removed ... destroy means destroy. If you're looking for a way to just close a session, that's [session_write_close()](http://php.net/session_write_close).

Comment: no users read other users session....  i am writing a server with php that only server read sessions

Comment: i think session_start() is not good ?? is there any other way to read sessions?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the server that's reading the session, that's still bad. As I said - just store the data in another place, from where you could easily read it.

Comment: you say it is better to read session from session file (from tmp folder) ??

Comment: No, I'm saying not to store that data in a session if you need to read it.